# Entire function (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

could anyone help me in proving about complex-valued polynomial is entire. I try to do something about this problem so far, but it seems no good in progress. I mess up with simplifying the form of polynomials. It make me feel dizzy.  Could anyone please suggest or give a hint ? Thank you very much in advanced.

Let $p$ be a complex-valued polynomial of two real variables :
$$p(z) = \sum_{ij} a_{ij}x^iy^j.$$Write $$p(z) = \sum_{j \geq 0} P_j(z)\bar{z}^j,$$
where each $P_j$ is of the form $P_j(z) = \sum b_{ij}z^i$ (a polynomial in $z$). Prove that $p$ is an entire function if and only if $$0 \equiv P_1 \equiv P_2 \equiv \cdots .$$ What can you conclude in this case for the matrix $[a_{ij}]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $\partial_{\bar{z}}p(z) = \sum_{j\ge 1} jP_j(z)\bar{z}^{j-1}$ and $p$ is entire if and only if $\partial_{\bar{z}}p(z) = 0$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Thank you very much. What a very tricky question ! I get it now. Anyway, let me ask you a bit more about the question concerning $[a_{ij}]$. Do I really need to tranform $p(z) = \sum_{ij}a_{ij}x^iy^j$ into $p(z) = \sum_{j \geq 0}P_j(z)\bar{z}^j$ to answer this question ? This might be messing up, I guess.

Comment: @Both you already know that $p(z) = P_0(z)$ when $p$ is entire. In any case, I suggest using the original form $p(x,y) = \sum a_{ij}x^i y^j$ and the Cauchy Riemann equations $p_x = -\sqrt{-1}p_y$ to find a relationship for $a_{ij}$.